# git add submodule with depth and branch options

Tags: git

Using git 2.4.3 (Fedora 22), I can clone a repo using the `--depth` and `-b` options:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 -b release https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro.git fonts/source-code-pro
Cloning into 'fonts/source-code-pro'...                                    
remote: Counting objects: 114, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (113/113), done.
remote: Total 114 (delta 1), reused 105 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (114/114), 7.27 MiB | 2.85 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

In theory `git submodule add` should support the same options. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /spare/local/arankine/foo/.git/
$ git submodule add --depth 1 -b release https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro.git fonts/source-code-pro                        
Cloning into 'fonts/source-code-pro'...
remote: Counting objects: 35853, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5932/5932), done.
remote: Total 35853 (delta 35196), reused 30018 (delta 29921), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (35853/35853), 12.95 MiB | 3.06 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35196/35196), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'release' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/release' which can not be resolved as commit?
Unable to checkout submodule 'fonts/source-code-pro'
```

The intention here is to minimize the disk space required for these fonts, which are distributed as binary objects on the `release` branch of that repo. Only the latest binaries are relevant.

It's not obvious to me how to make this work, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Add your submodule first, without mention of a branch.

Then [make your submodule track the right branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309):

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>

cd path/to/your/submodule
git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch
# if the master branch already exist:
git branch -u origin/master master
```

You might need to raise the depth in order to include commits part of the branch you want, instead of commits part of the default master branch.

Comment: How does this achieve the desired result? I think this does basically the same thing as omitting the `--depth` parameter from `submodule add`, or am I missing something? To be clear I've edited the question to describe the desired result.

Comment: @AlastairRankine the idea was to use submodule add with --depth, *then* try and switching branch.